# WireMock authenticating oAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, wiremock

I am using WireMock to mock an endpoint, I have it working successfully if I give the correct properties to the oAuth2RestTemplate to get an actual authentication token. If I give some mock details then my rest template doesn't get as far as the mock call.

I know I probably need to mock the authentication url but not really sure what to return..

Here is properties I have in properties file

```
my.service.clientId=<real-ID>
my.service.clientSecret=<real-secret>
my.service.audience=<real-audience>
my.service.BaseUrl=http://<real token url>/as/token.oauth2
my.service.url=http://localhost:8080/something/ #this stubs the actual endpoint
my.service.grantType=client_credentials
my.service.scopes=something.read
```

in my code i create the template using them properties

```
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = OauthTemplateUtil.createOauthRestTemplate(oauthProperties);
```

In my tests i configure the stubs like so

```
    private void configureStubs() {
        configureFor("localhost", 8080);

        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/<path>"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withBody("<my-json-response>");
}
```

This works fine, but i obviously don't want to use the real client and secret and make an actual call for my test, i presume i need to stub the my.service.BaseUrl but not sure what i should be returning back from it, just a 200? do i need to return a fake token and what should it look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how to configure for mocking the OauthProperties with rest template

```
my.service.clientId=mock-id
my.service.clientSecret=mock-secret
my.service.audience=mock-audience
my.service.BaseUrl=http://http://localhost:8080/as/token.oauth2
my.service.url=http://localhost:8080/something/ 
my.service.grantType=client_credentials
my.service.scopes=some.scope
```

```
    stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/as/token.oauth2?aud=https://mock-audience"))
            .willReturn(okJson("{\"token_type\": \"Bearer\",\"access_token\":\"{{randomValue length=20 type='ALPHANUMERIC'}}\"}")));
```